# Fetch a file from the client and upload it using php

Tags: php

I need to upload, say file1, file2, file3 to the server. I have used a file upload mechanism 
for the same. Instead of sending the three files from the client to the server, I planned to 
just read their names, and let the server fetch it from the client. I thought, it was 
possible initially, only to think otherwise now. Is it possible? Also, reading the client 
file using file_get_contents and copying it into a new file on the server would consume, some 
time. So dropped the latter idea.

Comment: Is it possible to assign values to the attributes, that follow 'file', i.e. its value, size and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't possible for a server to ask the client to upload specific files over HTTP.

Comment: Is there any other way to upload a file by using jquery post? I have built the file upload without the <form> tags, and hence the traditional method won't suffice.

Comment: No. If a server could request a file from a client, then it WILL be abused to steal any file the server wants from the client. The client MUST be the one to initiate the file upload. It'll never work the other way around.